# S3 Analytics read policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to allow a user permission to list all buckets, and read analytics on any bucket that has it enabled. I have following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucketsReadAnalytics",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I go to any S3 bucket's analytics I get the message:

```
Analyzing your data
We are analyzing your storage usage and will share the observed infrequent access patterns.
```

I don't get that when I access same buckets analytics with admin user. Is there a policy I am missing? I can't seem to Google this one, if someone knows good knowledge base or method to figuring which policies I need for action "x" please share.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, went with brute force, following is sufficient:

```
        {
            "Sid": "S3Analytics",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```